# Caffe didn't see hdf5.h when compiling

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I am having trouble when installing Caffe Deep Learning Framework on Python:

When I run `make` command at caffe directory, it says

> hdf5.h:no such directory

The steps I have done:

- Update and upgrade my Ubuntu Server
- Install Python 2.7
- Having all of the dependencies base on http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html
- Run cp cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
- Uncomment cpu_only = 1 in Makefile.config

I will be grateful if someone can help me.

Error message:

```
CXX src/caffe/util/hdf5.cpp
in file include from src/caffe/util/hdf5.cpp:1:0:
./include/caffe/util/hdf5.hpp:6:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated 

Makefile:572 recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/util/hdf5.o'       
failed Make:*** [.build_release/src/caffe/util/hdf5.o] Error 1
```

Comment: welcome to SO. please do not post screenshots, but rather copy-paste (and format) the error message to your question: this way search engines can better locate this thread in the future.

Comment: have you installed hdf5? look at http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html: `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev`

Comment: oh sorry about that i'm new,  i will change the screenshots. thank you for notifying me. yes i already installed hdf5.

Comment: Do you have `hdf5.h` on your system somewhere?  Try a command like `locate hdf5.h` to find out where it is, and post that here.

Comment: hi, i try to write `locate hdf5.h` as you suggest in my ubuntu terminal but nothing happen. so, i run another comment `find ~/  -type f -name "hdf5.h"` an the result is `/home/kelvin/opencv-3.1.0/modules/flann/include/opencv2/flann/hdf5.h`. Thank you

Answer (score 64):

What is the version of your Ubuntu install? Try this. In your `Makefile.config` try to append `/usr/include/hdf5/serial/` to `INCLUDE_DIRS`:

```
--- INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
+++ INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial/
```

and rename `hdf5_hl` and `hdf5` to `hdf5_serial_hl` and `hdf5_serial` in the `Makefile`:

```
--- LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf boost_system boost_filesystem m hdf5_hl hdf5
+++ LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf boost_system boost_filesystem m hdf5_serial_hl hdf5_serial
```

More about the bug fix [here](https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/679b05fcd1466bb0937f#fix-hdf5-naming-problem).

Comment: sorry for my late response, thank you for your help i already fix the problem by moving my hdf5 to the directory.

Comment: Thanks. That saves me time!

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me! Thanhs a lot!

Comment: This answer is indeed the best solution (i.e. instead of moving the hdf5 dir.) @kelvin : Could you mark this answer as correct?

Comment: I just added 'LIBRARIES +=  ' string. I don't have any and it seems working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved my problem

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 18.04 without adding the LIBRARIES part.

Comment: indeed! Might also be worth to check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1276813/1732034), as MMV depending on system, some ln might be needed

Answer (score 30):

This solution worked for me on the `Ubuntu16.04LTS`

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-10
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-cpp-11
find /usr -iname "*hdf5.h*"
/usr/include/hdf5/serial/hdf5.h
export CPATH="/usr/include/hdf5/serial/"
```

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: Worked for me three!

Comment: just `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-10 libhdf5-serial-dev` worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Another case I've experienced with:

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and installing **hdf5-1.10.0**.

I found `hdf5.h` was located in `/usr/local/hdf5/include`. Thus, I modified `Makefile.config` file by adding that location to `INCLUDE_DIRS`.

```
# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include \
                    /usr/local/hdf5/include
```

I didn't rename anything in `Makefile`. It worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

It did not work for me on Ubuntu16.04 LTS.

So I had to

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-10
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-cpp-11
find /usr -iname "*hdf5.h*"
/usr/include/hdf5/serial/hdf5.h
```

Now do this

```
export CPATH="/usr/include/hdf5/serial/"
```

Answer (score 1):

On **RHEL7**, I got tired of hunting for specific `hdf5` RPMs and ran:

```
sudo yum install *hdf5*
```

and these are what I have:

```
hdf5-openmpi3-static-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
hdf5-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
hdf5-openmpi-static-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
hdf5-openmpi3-devel-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
hdf5-openmpi3-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
hdf5-mpich-devel-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
hdf5-devel-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
hdf5-mpich-static-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
hdf5-mpich-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
hdf5-openmpi-1.8.12-11.el7.x86_64
```

Thanks to @loretoparisi, I was able to figure out where I had the header file I was missing and the problem went away.

```
$ find /usr -iname "*hdf5.h*"
/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/hdf5.h
/usr/include/hdf5.h
/usr/include/mpich-x86_64/hdf5.h
/usr/include/openmpi3-x86_64/hdf5.h
```