# “No module named caffe” error when trying to run python program

Tags: python, caffe, deep-dream

I recently started with deep dreaming VFX,but I got this error after I typed in the bash `python video.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video.py", line 19, in <module>
    import caffe
ImportError: No module named caffe
```

I am a newbie at this, and I looked it up for 3 days and I still have no clue, can someone help? I tried to install caffe using [these instructions](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2016/05/25/generating-deep-dreams/) but I keep getting errors when I run `make all`. On another thread they said to download and set up OpenCV for it to work, and that too failed...

These are the errors I got while installing Caffe

```
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cpp
src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cpp:13:10: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
 #include "hdf5.h"
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:581: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.o] Error 1
```

and this is the error I got while trying to finish setting up OpenCV:

```
c@c-VirtualBox:~/opencv$ python removeRedEyes.py
python: can't open file 'removeRedEyes.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

While there are many posts about this, they all seem to be outdated from 2015 to 2016.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007495/caffe-didnt-see-hdf5-h-when-compiling

Comment: @hootnot That appears to be outdated... Did  you you not read my question?

Comment: I saw somewhere halfway down with a score of 11 an answer (july 2017) installing packages related to hdf5-dev containing the *hdf5.h* file. Not having that seems to be one of your issues.

Comment: Alright send me the link then...

Comment: ? ... see first comment

Comment: That's outdated, from 2016...

Comment: the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007495/caffe-didnt-see-hdf5-h-when-compiling  I referred is dated: *answered Jul 4 '17 at 18:37*

Comment: Also, for `import caffe` to work, you need `make all` and `make pycaffe` to succeed first.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Linux, add `+++ INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial/` to your Makefile.config